# MySQL change default session date

Tags: mysql

In need to change the default date in MySQL to a future date.

So if today's date is 2012-07-30 (YYYY-MM-DD) I want to be able to set my MySQL session date to a future date, for example 2012-08-05.

So, when I do

```
select curdate()
```

curdate(): 2012-07-30

Change the MySQL session date to 2012-08-05

```
select curdate()
```

curdate():  2012-08-05

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SET TIMESTAMP=unix_timestamp('2012-08-05');
```

Comment: To set back to default I used "set timestamp=default;"